# Why an emotion is "often" accompanied by a bodily reaction?

Tags: emotion

Baumeister and Bushman (2007) have given this definition of emotion:

> a subjective state, often accompanied by a bodily reaction (e.g., increased heart rate) and an evaluative response, to some event

But I thought that emotion (see the synthesis in [SE psycho here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/what-causes-emotions?rq=1)) is normally understood as the interpretation of an affect, affect which is a bodily reaction; so that you cannot have an emotion without having a bodily reaction, and so it is not that an emotion is *often* accompanied by a bodily reaction, but is *always* accompanied by a bodily reaction.

The wikipedia of [Appraisal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appraisal_theory) also states my understanding:

> According to Schachter and Singer (1962)[26] we can have arousal without emotion, but we cannot have an emotion without arousal.

This question is based on the consensus among Constructionists.

**References:**

Baumeister, R. F., & Bushman, B. J. (2007). Angry emotions and aggressive behaviors. In G. Steffgen & M. Gollwitzer (Eds.), *Emotions and aggressive behavior* (pp. 61–75). Ashland, OH: Hogrefe & Huber.

Comment: Considering the other question you linked, are you wanting to base this question on the concensus among Basic Emotion Theorists, or Constructionists?

Comment: @ChrisRogers On the Constructionists